# will installing Xubuntu on C drive erase all other partition drives?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, filesystem

I'm totally new to Linux world. I'm going to install Xubuntu on my laptop, it has 3 drives C,D and E, all these 3 are of NTFS type. Currently C has Windows 10 installed in it.

Now before going on with linux installation I wanted to confirm whether installing Xubuntu on C drive (currently having Windows installation) format other drives: D and E? If not then would I be able to use (read/write) data to D, E drives on xubuntu normally as I currently do in Windows?

The thing is that up till now I've only been doing Windows installs and it did not affect the partitions other than the one in which it was going to be installed, i want to confirm if it will be the same in Xubuntu's case, as i do not want to lose my data present in D and E drives. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on your configuration:

- If you intend to use "Install alongside Windows"

  Then you shouldn't have any issues.

---

- If you intend to use "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"

  - If `D:\` and `E:\` are on the same physical disk (ie. they're just different partitions) then they will get nuked along with `C:\`.
  - If `D:\` and `E:\` are seperate disks, they will remain intact

---

Note on Linux partitioning:

Linux does not access drives with letters like Windows does. Instead, each disk/partition is given a block device. Let's say you have two disks: disk A has two partitions, `X:\` and `Y:\`, and disk B only has one partition, `Z:\`

Here's how the drives would show up in Linux:

```
/dev/sda        #This is disk A
    /dev/sda1   #This is the 1st partition on disk A,  X:\
    /dev/sda2   #This is the 2nd partition on disk A,  Y:\

/dev/sdb        #This is disk B
    /dev/sdb1   #This is the only partition disk B,    Z:\
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this cleared up a lot of things for me.
1) If I want to keep only Xubuntu and erase Windows (not erasing my D and E partitions)? What should I be doing?
Should I install Xubuntu directly onto C partition, would it work?

2)In case I want to do a dual boot, should I be choosing 2 different logical partitions or it can work with both OS being in one partition?

Comment: and all these logical partitions are made on single hard drive

Comment: First of all, backup. Then you need to use the last option - Something else - instead of the ones mentioned in the answer and do a manual partitioning.